# Dynamic callback method

Tags: c#

I have a situation where I loop over items and assign a "callback" method based on some calculations, at the end of loop this method is called (method that "won" based on priority and calculations).

It's super easy in dynamically typed language like JS but because I'm new to typed language, I need some help with dynamic callback method.

Please read the comments:

```cs
bool MethodA(MyClass item, List<MyClass> items) {
  int priority = 0;
  // here should be local variable for method,
  // for example in JS it would be "var func;"

  for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++) {
    if (priority <= 4) {
      float expensiveValue;
      if (MethodB(item, items[i], out expensiveValue)) {
        priority = 4;
        // assing a callback "func" that use "expensiveValue"
        // so that I don't have to calculate it again, e.g in JS: 
        /* func = function () {
          // use "expensiveValue", it's bound to this context
          return true;
        }; */
      }
    }
    if (priority <= 3) {
      float expensiveValue = MethodC(item, items);
      if (expensiveValue > 5f) {
        priority = 3;
        // same as in "if (priority <= 4)"
      }
    }
    // and other priority if's
  }

  // now that for loop is done, one of these callbacks 
  // was assigned to "func", in JS I'd call "return func();"
}
```

**Edit: few examples of callback methods**

`bool` is always returned but parameters differ.

```cs
bool Method1(MyClass items[i], Vector3 expensiveValue);
bool Method2(MyClass items[i], float expensiveValue);
```

Comment: Please don't tag languages your question isn't about, even if you mention them in the text. This is a [tag:C#] question, not a [tag:javascript] question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the interesting problem. The current answers are great and provide a way to do what you've asked with C#.  I'd suggest an alternative to make the code easier to test and, for me, a little more clear.  The crux of what you've been doing in javascript is capturing the locally scoped variables which is cool but also makes this type of code hard to test and a little confusing.  One thing that is often done is to lift those variables out into their own class.  You can do the same with the selection code.  For example:

```
class PriorityMethod
{
    public virtual bool Invoke()
    {
        return false; 
    }
}

class MethodPriorityB : PriorityMethod
{
    public MyClass FirstItem { get; set; }
    public MyClass SecondItem { get; set; }

    public float ExpensiveValue { get; set; }

    public override bool Invoke()
    {
        // use the properties to derive your result...
        return true;
    }
}
```

These two - from your example obviously it would be more than just the one child class - represent the methods and their scoped variables that we want to invoke in the end.  The selection logic we could extract out in something like this:

```
class PriorityMethodSelector
{
    public PriorityMethod Create(ref int priority, MyClass first, MyClass second)
    {
        if (priority <= 4)
        {
            // do something to drive the expensive value
            return new MethodPriorityB() { FirstItem = first, SecondItem = second, ExpensiveValue = 1 };
        }

        return null;
    }

    public PriorityMethod Create(ref int priorty, MyClass first, IEnumerable<MyClass> items)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then we just put it all together:

```
        PriorityMethodSelector selector = new PriorityMethodSelector();
        int priority = 0;
        PriorityMethod method = null;

        foreach(var item in items)
        {
            method = selector.Create(ref priority, special, item) ?? method;
            method = selector.Create(ref priority, item, items) ?? method;
        }

        if (null != method)
            method.Invoke();
```

Another alternative that I've seen used for this type of problem is to use a state machine.  That would add even more complexity but is useful if your selection logic gets more complex.

Answer (score 0):

In c# you can store references to methods using [delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/).

First you have to declare your delegate

```
delegate bool MyDelegate();
```

Then you can declare variable with type of that delegate

```
MyDelegate myDelegate;
```

Now if you have method matching that delegate, like

```
static bool MyMethod() => true;
```

You can assign it just like that

```
myDelegate = MyMethod;
```

And then use `Invoke` to call that method

```
bool b = myDelegate.Invoke();
```

In your case methods take different parameters but they all return `bool` so you can wrap them in [lambda expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions) like this

```
myDelegate = () => MyMethod1(5);
```

For a method which takes single int as a parameter, for example one like ths

```
static bool MyMethod1(int i) => true;
```

This console application decides which method to invoke based on value of `condition` variable

```
delegate bool MyDelegate();

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyDelegate myDelegate;
    bool condition = false;

    if (condition) myDelegate = () => MyMethod1(5);
    else myDelegate = () => MyMethod2(7, "hello there");

    Console.WriteLine(myDelegate.Invoke());

    Console.ReadLine();
}

static bool MyMethod1(int i) => true;
static bool MyMethod2(int i, string s) => false;
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm trying to figure out how to apply it to my situation where each `if` block has different callback method. Would I have to make different delegates for each?

Comment: Do your methods differ in return types and/or parameter types and/or parameter count? Perhaps including a bit more code in your example, like at least two method declarations, would make this more clear

Comment: Added few examples.

Comment: I updated my answer based on new examples in your question

Answer (score 0):

```
  float expensiveValue;
  Func<float> callback;
  if (MethodB(item, items[i], out expensiveValue)) {
    callback = () => {return expensiveValue;}
  }

  float result = callback.Invoke();

  // ..or..
  float expensiveValue;
  Func<float, float> callback = (val) => {return val;};
  if (MethodB(item, items[i], out expensiveValue)) {
    float result = callback.Invoke(expensiveValue);
  }
```